# ASP.NET MVC returns corrupted file with wrong size

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have a problem - ASP.NET MVC returns file with wrong size, therefore it is corrupted and cant open it. All files on server are good and i can open them, so the problem is in returning and downloading files, also, only some files are corrupted when downloaded, and most files are good. And on rare occasions, files, that downloads in wrong size, gets downloaded in correct size. File sizes are up to 500kb. The code wasnt changed for long time, and only now it started to return files with wrong sizes. The code is simple:

```
public ActionResult GetFile(string fileName)
{
    var contentType = "image/jpeg";
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(Path.Combine("c:\myFilesDirectory", fileName)))
    {
        return this.File(Path.Combine("c:\myFilesDirectory", fileName), contentType, fileName);
    }
}
```

What is wrong with it ?

Comment: How do these files get onto the server? Is it possible that the file is only half written to the disk when it gets downloaded?

Comment: What do you see when opening the file with notepad or a hex editor? Do you see human readable code? Maybe even HTML? What if you compare both files from server and client?

Comment: No, the files are uploaded via web site to server, but as i said, i can open all files on the server, so all files are fully uploaded to the server and with correct size. And instead of file with size 144kb, i get something like 236kb.

Comment: Are you sure that all the uploaded files are `jpeg`s?

Comment: I used approach like in this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2008/11/13/extending-mvc-returning-an-image-from-a-controller-action.aspx) and never got such problem like in your post, if you sure that all your images are jpeg you can try it also.

Comment: Not all files are images, i just made it short for example, but files types are identified correctly. Will try to look with hex editor at corrupted file.

Comment: Well, corrupted file is almost twice as big as original file, and many symbols of original file are replaced with symbol �.

Comment: Many symbols of original file are replaced with hex symbols combination EF BF BD.

Comment: Have you tried changing the returned object to a different type? i.e. - FileContentResult for instance?

Comment: Interesting part : If i include logging into code, then everything is working ok and files are downloaded with correct size... i.e.:
    ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        logger.Error(string.Format("fileName = " + fileName));
        logger.Error(string.Format("contentType = " + contentType));
        logger.Error(string.Format("failas exists,path = " + pathDir));

Comment: Any luck with this? I know it's a few years old but I'm having pretty much the same problem. Even more curious is that the same controller code works from one Azure web app but not from another. The file size is significantly (not 2x) larger and the file is 'altered'